# Access javascript object value by array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like: `const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }` and I have an array like `const arr = ['abc', 'def']` How can I access `obj.abc.def` property of my object with the array?

Obviously, `obj[arr]` doesn't work, also `obj[arr.join('.')` doesn't work.

What I want to do is:

```
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }  
const arr = ['abc', 'def']

const value = obj[arr] // crash 
// value should contain 1
```

Comment: It's my questioning nature. I just can't help myself. **Why**? Why would you ever want or need to do this? In my experience, if you find yourself needing to do something this edge case there's a bigger flaw in you design than this. Think about it. Every answer is going to be some variation of a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a dynamic approach and reduce the keys and take a default object, if a part is not accessable.

```js
const
    getValue = (object, keys) => keys.reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object),
    obj = { abc: { def: 1 } },
    arr = ['abc', 'def'],
    value = getValue(obj, arr);

console.log(value);
console.log(getValue(obj, ['foo', 'bar']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the array property by index only. so `arr[0]` will work.

```js
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }  
const arr = ['abc', 'def']

const value = obj[arr[0]][arr[1]]
console.log(value)
```

or you can run the loop over it.

```js
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def' : {'ghi': 1 } } };
const arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
let ans = null;

for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if(i==0) {
    ans = obj[arr[0]];
  }
  else {
    ans = ans[arr[i]];
  }
}
console.log(ans)
```

Comment: But that indicates that I need to know before how deep the object is nested which I don't know.

Comment: You can run the loop over it in that case.

Comment: The depth of the property will be `arr.length`

Comment: You can try the updated answer. BTW @hev1 has given a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The base is

```js
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }  
const arr = ['abc', 'def']

console.log(obj[arr[0]][arr[1]]);
```

or if you need to do it with a function...

```js
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }  
const arr = ['abc', 'def']

function access(obj, arr) {
  return arr.reduce((o, key) => o[key], obj);
}

console.log(access(obj, arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }  
const arr = ['abc', 'def']

var value = obj;

for(let key of arr){
  value = value[key];
}

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce` for a dynamic array.

```js
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }  
const arr = ['abc', 'def']
const res = arr.reduce((o,prop)=>o[prop], obj);
console.log(res);
```

If you do not want errors to be thrown on properties that do not exist, you can use the optional chaining operator.

```js
const obj =  { 'abc': {'def': 1 } }  
const arr = ['abc', 'def', 'notdefined', 'notdefined2']
const res = arr.reduce((o,prop)=>o?.[prop], obj);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is somewhat called object value "get by path", some library have support this and for example [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) is a production-ready library for that, you should not try to reinvent the wheel (practice is okay)

In your context, ramda's [path](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) method could help you achieve to the case of arbitrary array of properties

```js
const obj = {
  'abc': {
    'def': 1,
    'ghi': {
      'jkl': 10
    }
  }
}

console.log(R.path(['abc', 'def'], obj))
console.log(R.path(['abc', 'ghi'], obj))
console.log(R.path(['abc', 'ghi', 'jkl'], obj))
console.log(R.path(['abc', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'], obj))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "reinventing the wheel" is generally not an issue for small/simple ideas, on the other hand, including an entire library just for this snippet seems excessive and inefficient. (If you already use a library that has this functionality, by all means use it, but don't add a library just for this)